# PHP doesn't read from MySQL database with POST or GET queries.(blank output)

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

I am trying to make a basic login system with PHP and MySQL, and it is not working from my login form. Here is the code for the login form.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="verify.php">
<br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
<br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
<br/><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code for verify.php:

```
<?php
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"]; //Not Doing anything with the pass yet
        $con=mysqli_connect("","root","mypassword","logins");
        //now mySQL is connected, lets extract stuff from the database
        $que = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Pass FROM login WHERE User='" . $username . "'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($que);
        $myvar = $row[0];
        //should echo Test
        echo $myvar;
        echo "If it returned Test, the mySQL works.";
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I run this, the output is completly blank.
However, I can get the query directly from the MySQL console:

```
    mysql> SELECT Pass from login WHERE User='Logern';
    +------+
    | Pass |
    +------+
    | Test |
    +------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)
    mysql>
```

I can also acsess it from PHP, with a hardcoded SQL Query:

```
$que = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Pass FROM login WHERE User='Logern'");
```

So why is this failing to work? My webserver is a Raspberry Pi with Debian and lighttpd.

Comment: before looking in to the answer you (and anyone else taking this approach) should know that taking plain input from `$_POST` and using it in a MySQL query leaves your app wide open for SQL injection attacks: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Yes, I know, but I will worry about security later, this is just a private webserver anyway.

Comment: ok, just making sure for others then; also, you may fix the sample by changing `$password = $_POST["password"[;` to `$password = $_POST["password"];`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in here ->

```
$password = $_POST["password"[; //Not Doing anything with the pass yet
```

It is obvious that it should be

```
$password = $_POST["password"]; //Not Doing anything with the pass yet
```

So, due to this syntax error, the entire code gets kind-of 'uncompiled', so a blank page is what you get.

Comment: ack, that seems to be the problem indeed since the rest looks ok

Comment: I fixed that, no change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a blank return is because your display_errors directive is turned off in your php.ini file as I can see two problems in your script straight away:

```
$password = $_POST["password"[;
```

should be

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

And the host in your connection:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","root","mypassword","logins");
```

should be

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","logins");
```

Please turn on your display_errors directive or go to the error log to see the errors.

Comment: It does work with no host, with that hardcoded query string, though.

Comment: Ok, it's probably converting the empty string to localhost. But turn your errors ON so you can see this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: I turned on display_errors, no errors are being reported.

Comment: Did you restart apache after turning it on?

Comment: No,not yet, ill restart my lighttpd (not using apache).

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, after restarting lighttpd, it magically works! Slightly modified code:

```
<?php
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"]; //Not Doing anything with the pass yet
        $con=mysqli_connect("","root","mypassword","logins");
        //now mySQL is connected, lets extract stuff from the database
        $sql = "SELECT Pass FROM login WHERE User='" . $username . "'";
        //$que = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Pass FROM login WHERE User='" . $username . "';");
        $que = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($que);
        $myvar = $row[0];
        //should echo Test
        echo $myvar;
        echo "If it returned Test, the mySQL works.";
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","root","mypassword","logins");
```

edit connect host.(password and user name is correct.)

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","logins");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using like this:

you should never use connect statement on each and every page mane a connection.php file write the connection code there and include it on the pages and access through mysqli object.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); // see if you have any error in connection database.

//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT Pass FROM login WHERE User='" . $username . "'"; 
// echo $query; // use echo and see what your query looks like
//execute the query. 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//display information: 

 $myvar = $row[0];
        //should echo Test
        echo $myvar;
        echo "If it returned Test, the mySQL works.";
```